# How to check the password from an EditView?

Tags: java, android, passwords, equals, android-edittext

I use an `EditText` with `android:password="true"` to let the user type the password. Then I want to compare the password with a hard coded password when the user presses a button.

But I can't compare the password with a String "mypassword". Here is the code I use to check the password:

```
EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwdTxt);
if(pw.getText().equals("mypassword")) {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LinkpageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
} else {
    // Wrong password
}
```

The comparison `pw.getText().equals("mypassword")` returns `false` even if I type the correct password. How should I check the password from an `EditText`?

Comment: Another thing, the `android:password` property is deprecated. Instead Change `InputType` to `textPassword` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try

```
pw.getText().toString().equals("mypassword")
```